# Using Android Management API without google account

Tags: android-management-api, device-owner, android-enterprise, emm

I am developing an application in the "fully managed device" mode. Now implemented "Dedicated devices". The installation of the application is carried out via a QR code immediately in the "Device owner" mode.

```
{
  "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME": "your_name",
  "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_SIGNATURE_CHECKSUM": "your_checksum",
  "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION": "your_location",
  "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_USE_MOBILE_DATA":true
}
```

The problem is that after installing the application, there is a need to give permissions and configure some areas of the smartphone (such as disabling auto-update software, installing from unknown sources) in order to work correctly in a fully managed mode. As I understand it, using the Android Management API, you can set up a [policy](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies) to immediately grant part of the permissions. But all the examples that describe the Android Management API mention working through a google account and google play market for enterprice solutions.

Is it possible to do without a google account? I understand that all examples are tied to EMM from google, and if I don't want to be tied to google, I either need to use a third-party EMM API or implement my own, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use Android Management API without an EMM, you need to create a Service Account and create a new Enterprise with a  gmail account,You will be able to provision device to the Enterprise and  set up policies for those devices.This notebook will show you how to get started https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/google/android-management-api-samples/blob/master/notebooks/quickstart.ipynb